# How to make 'required' AND 'format' conditional in jQuery Validate plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got a form that has several inputs. two of them are 'country' and 'postcode'.
Now i want 'postcode' to be required and in proper postcodeformat unless the country isNOT 'NL'. Then postcode is not required and can have any format. I've tried this. 
But somehow when the country is set to other then NL the input is no longer required (ok) but the formating for postcode is still checked and returns an error msg. 
*(the code is shortened for better reading)*

```
function setupValidator() {
    $.validator.addMethod("postcodeFormat",
        function (value, element) {
            console.log(element, value)
            return this.optional(element) || /[1-9][0-9]{3} ?[a-zA-Z]{2}/.test(value);
        },
        "vul een geldig postcode in"
    );

    $("#donatieform").validate({
        rules :{
           postcode :{required:function(){return $("#country").val() === 'NL';}, postcodeFormat:function(element){return $("#country").val() === 'NL';} },
        },

        focusInvalid  :false
    });
}
```

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove validation class in jQuery like

```
  if($('#CountryId').val() !="")
    $(selector).rules('add', 'your rule name');
   else
    $(selector).rules('remove', 'your rule name)'
```

Comment: I understand but where would i put this code in the validation setup? Also what would be the 'name' of my rule.my rules are just name;value pairs and do not have an instanciated var name?

Answer (score 0):

You've made it a little more complicate than it needed to be.  I simply modified your custom method a bit to check the country and removed the part that makes it `optional`.  Then I simplified how you declare the `postcodeFormat` rule within `.validate()`.

I also used the `depends` option on the `required` rule to only make "Postcode" required when "Country" is filled out with something.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ptUft/2**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("postcodeFormat", function (value, element) {
        if ($('#country').val() == 'NL') {
            return  (/[1-9][0-9]{3} ?[a-zA-Z]{2}/).test(value);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }, "vul een geldig postcode in");

    $("#donatieform").validate({
        rules: {
            postcode: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $('#country').is(':filled')
                    }
                },
                postcodeFormat: true
            }
        },
        focusInvalid: false
    });

});
```

---

**EDIT**:

After exchanging comments with the OP, I believe I've edited it so that it's now working as he desires.

However, the code in his OP was working the same all along:

http://jsfiddle.net/mDdCn/

Comment: But then postcode is no longer `required` I also need it to be required unless country != 'NL'

Comment: @user1226692, you're speaking in double negatives...  "Unless Not".  Then why not simply say you need Postcode to be required and formatted when the Country == NL?  Here is the exact opposite of my original answer:  http://jsfiddle.net/ptUft/1/

Comment: @user1226692, I guess you also missed the point of my answer, which was to show you how a custom method works and how easy it would be for you to tweak it to your exact specifications.

Comment: @ sparky: tnx. the thing with 2 rules is that they each get they're own 'message'. so when PC is not filledout it says 'PC required' andd when the format is wrong i get 'PC format is wrong'. so having 2 rules has an advantage. Any ideas why my original code refuses to return TRUE for each of the rules and how to fix that?

Comment: @user1226692, the logic of your original code says that the two rules, `required` and `postcodeFormat` on PC are only applied when "Country" contains "NL" and it appears to be working for me.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/mDdCn/ ~ And as per your last comment, I also now have the new jsFiddle in my latest edit working the same:  http://jsfiddle.net/ptUft/2/